# Linux socket C/C++ - What is the best way to check if ip/port is already in use?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a system that can start multiple instances.
Every instance has a client and a server.
They are connected over socket/TCP

Every instance is started by starting a client.
The client starts (checks if IP is available, if not increase the IP by 1, checks again ...) -
The client starts the server with the free IP and connects to it. (for legacy reasons has to be like this)

Instance numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 work without issues.
...

Instance number 6.  -> Fails on checking if the first IP in the range is available.

To check if IP is already in use, I do not close the socket on the server side so that it can accept the additional connection.
On the client-side, I check if I can connect to the server-side with the following code:

```
bool CheckIPInUse(char *ip)
{
    bool ret = false;
    int port = 12345;
    int sock;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    // **non blocking** because I want the check to be fast. 
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &serv_addr.sin_addr);

    int ret_conn = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (ret_conn == 0){
        fprintf(stdout, "connected");
        ret = true;
    }
    else if (ret_conn < 0 && (errno != EINPROGRESS)){
        fprintf(stdout, "failed to connect");
    }
    else
    {
        int check_if_connected = 10;

        while (check_if_connected--)
        {
            socklen_t len = sizeof(serv_addr);
            int ret_getpeer = getpeername(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, &len);
            if (ret_getpeer == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "connected");
                ret = true;

                break;
            }
            usleep(100000);
        }
    }
    close(sock);
    return ret;
}
```

This works for the first 5 instances.
6th instance fails to connect to the first IP in range and tries to start the server with IP which is already in use. (always the 6th).

Is there any better way to check programmatically if IP/Port is already busy?
Any ideas on what to check. for failure in the instance number 6?

Comment: How do you increment the IP address? Where's your error checking of `inet_pton()`'s return value?

Comment: If you're going to do a non-blocking connect for whatever reason, you should use `poll()` with a timeout instead of that loop...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check if an ip/port on a server is available is to `bind()` to it. If it worked, it ***was*** available (but not any more).

Any approach that involves a test `connect()`ion first, to see if it fails, or anything along the lines of poking somewhere in `/proc` to see which IPs and ports are in use -- nothing along these lines will ever be 100% foolproof. That's because even if you reach the conclusion that the port is available, it may no longer be by the time you get around to try to `bind()` to it.

Now, you can take, as a starting position, that a particular IP and/or port range is reserved for your application's use, and you only wish to arbitrate IP/port allocation between different instances of your application. In that case you can do that pretty much whatever you want, you're not limited to attempting to actually start instances of your application, and hope for the best. One simplistic approach is to use lock files in `/var/tmp` to represent all possible IP/port combination, and have your application try, in turn, to acquire a lock on the corresponding lock file, first, and once it's official, and the lock file is acquired, then the corresponding IP/port then can be established at your leisure, but the lock file must remain locked until the IP/port is no longer in use.

But in terms of attempting to check if a socket port is available, or not, the only way to do it is to `bind()` it, because that, by definition, is what it does. You could attempt to implement a multi-layered approach, like trying to `connect()` first, and then attempt to `bind()` it, and if the `bind()` fails, then keep looking for a free port. But that's creating extra complexity, without much of a benefit.

Comment: I'm afraid that the OP is asking for the _server_ availability in a full connected instance.  This justifies the 5 limit he is observing, and the point of view he is using in his description (the one from the client, not the one from the server)  I'm afraid that, if you are the one that has downvoted the answer of @barakFriedman, you have done it erroneously (and with no explanation at all)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the server did not meet its maximum backlog length ?
You may be getting "connection refused" if the server you are trying to connect to
has more pending connections then the defined backlog.
So if multiple clients are testing at the same time, one of them may encounter this.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of your problem is that your client is getting a connect from the server due to the listen queue.  The best way to avoid this problem is to close the socket on which you call `accept(2)` once all the instances are in use, and reopen it again when any of the server instances are finished.

The listen queue makes the kernel to accept (send the SYN/ACK segment) connections on the *otherwise not yet open* socket waiting, and this will make the connection establishment quicker for the next server instances if many such connections are entering in the system.  All those connections are handled in the `accept(2)` socket, so the best way to accept five such connections is to close the accept socket as soon as the last connection has been established (this will not avoid  the problem if a connection happens to enter the server in the time between one `accept(2)` and the next, but the connection so established will be closed as soon as the accept socket is still open)

In my opinion, you should have a master server process that forks new processes to handle the different connection and closes the accept socket as soon as it reaches the full capacity.  Once one of the servers attending the connections closes one of them, it should reopen the accept socket and accept a new connection.

IMHO, also the most robust way of implementing such a system is to allow the extra connections to get in, but not attend them, so the connection remains open in case a new client happens to enter, and it can close it if the server doesn't attend it in a timeout interval.  Having a sixth client already connected, but waiting for the server to say hello, will leave you in a state in which you can start talking to the server as soon as the last service ends.